# databinding - MediatorLiveData not firing inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm facing some issues with a MediatorLiveData inside a fragment.

For example:

I have a `View Model`:

```
class InfoPessoalViewModel : NavigationViewModel(){

//fields
val nameField = MutableLiveData<String>()

val formMediator = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()

init {
    formMediator.addSource(nameField){}
}
```

And I'm putting this name inside my xml by databinding

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="@{viewModel.nameField}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

But the observer its not firing inside my fragment.

```
bindingView.apply {
            lifecycleOwner = this@InfoFragment
            viewModel = viewModel
        }

        viewModel.formMediator.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.d("Mediator","Fired!")
        })
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I have changed to two-way binding here

`android:text="@={viewModel.nameField}"`

But none of this have fired yet

```
    viewModel.nameField.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("Livedata","Fired!")
    })

    viewModel.formMediator.observe(this, Observer {
        Log.d("Livedata","Fired!")
    })
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm importing this viewModel, like this:

```
  <data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="br.com.original.bank.sejaoriginal.steps.infopersonal.InfoPessoalViewModel" />
</data>
```

And binding view inside my fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    bindingView = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_info_pessoal,container,false)

    return bindingView.root
}
```

**EDIT 3**

So, the initial problem was with `viewModel = viewModel`, with wrong reference inside `apply` method.

But the problem with `MediatorLiveData` not being called still

Comment: What are trying to achive? Do you want to get notified when the nameField changes or formMediator? If so, are you actually putting a new value into your formMediator livedata?

Comment: @Mordag I want to be notified when nameField changes. I have a form and a submit button, this button need to be disable until the last field of form be checked. So, basically I am listening to this mediator data, who I put all my fields inside it with addSource

Comment: You probably should consider using a two-way-binding for that. Regarding listening to changes, I would recommend using a ObservableField<String> object. This class provides a property change callback. But of course you can also use a livedata but you need to observe each relevant livedata in order to get changes. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah, a little. But in this case, `viewModel.nameField.observe` should fire right? But it does not.

Comment: That is probably because of your missing two-way binding.

Comment: Nah, I have changed this and didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Check those steps in sequence:

1) Change this:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.nameField}"
```

to this (note the additional equals symbol) :

```
android:text="@={viewModel.nameField}"
```

> More info about 2-way data binding [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

2) Check that you added the correct viewmodel binding in the XML layout:

[image]

3) Check the code binding, change your binding code to this:

```
bindingView.apply {
    lifecycleOwner = this@InfoFragment
    viewModel = this@InfoFragment.viewModel
}
```

Comment: If you init your `nameField` livedata with a string do you see it in the view? Because if you don't see it you have misconfigured databinding for sure

Comment: when I init nameField, the observer is being fired but I didnt see anything in my view.

Comment: Added a new piece in the answer, check that you imported the correct viewmodel. if this is correct you need to provide more Fragment code to your question

Comment: I've added the last piece i can come to mind in the answer. Check that your binding code is referring to the right viewmodel instance and not self-referencing with `viewModel = viewModel`

Comment: I have updated my question with this piece of code. I'm importing viewmodel correctly, I think. The point about wrong reference is interesting, I'll change the name of my viewModel, to be secure

Comment: WOW! The problem was with `viewModel = viewModel`, taking the wrong reference inside `apply`. Now `nameField.observe` is being fired but `formMediator.observe` dont.

Comment: not really, I really want to observe only `formMediator`. But its not being fired. Only field by field

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped me, although this  post did not have the problem I had:

if you have a function that returns a livedata, like fun myName(): LiveData {
return myLiveName
},

the view model binding will not show value in xml layout. The live data has to be a variable, not funtion, like:
val myNameVariable: LiveData = myName()